# Trying to log a long body response from a get request in eclipse using maven

Tags: java, eclipse, api, maven, automation

as the title says, I am using RestAssured to test API response and I need to log all the body response but eclipse is showing me only a part of it (like 1600 records but they are like 13,000) is there a form to say to eclipse I want ALL the body response shown?

I am using:

```
public class MavenBasics {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    

    RestAssured.baseURI= "http://tokkobroker.com";
    given().log().all().queryParam("api_key", "3e9s17d5w9a8g845acbe4ddd536d8f").queryParam("format", "json").queryParam("lang", "es-MX")
    .when().get("/portals/simple_portal/api/v1/freeportals/")
    .then().log().all().headers().assertThat().statusCode(200).header("server", "cloudflare");
    }
}*
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean that the eclipse console is logging only limited portion then it could be because of console preferences.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help! that worked , I am rookie just begining with programming and this was great thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

**Console buffer** can be increased

[image]

Additionally, **Run configuration output** can be redirected to a file in `Common` tab

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help! that worked , I am rookie just begining with programming and this was great thanks a lot :)

Comment: Unfortunately, the other answer was accepted even when it was added after mine and says the same as mine. Sh*t happens, I know.

Comment: I am sorry about that, I am also knew at Stack Overflow I didn't even know that I could only accept one answer, I just clicked on the check Icon ✔️ for both answers, Sorry about that and thank you for your help and feedback

Comment: It's ok, no problem.